# Some picture of my site are broken in mobile version

Tags: image

Some picture of my site are broken in Mobile version . But they are perfectly ok and showing in pc . this is only happen to mobile version. If you vist the page then look at the picture beside 'Buy now' button in mobile version .
Link : http://www.hlwphone.com/iphone-xs/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is those image URLs start with `http://localhost/` instead of (presumably) `http://www.hlwphone.com/`. It's actually unrelated to desktop vs. mobile; you just notice it on mobile because then you're not looking at it on the same computer as the Web server.